# Move the focus to textbox after MouseDrop event in GOJS

Tags: javascript, gojs

How can i move the focus to the textbox after i have completed the mouse Drop event in GOJS

Example is here : [GoJS Sample](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartEditor.html)

Repro step in the Sample is:
Drag one of the object in the diagram and you will see a form show up. Ideally i would like to be able to set focus on the comments textbox in that form

I was able to get the DOM element in the and set focus on it but it should be done after the mouseDrop event since at the end of mouseDropEvent it will set the focus on the gojs diagram or Object depending on the paramaters passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest setting focus on the desired HTML input element in a `setTimeout` function.